# Fastest way to access Data by Key

Tags: delphi, generics

I have hundreds of variables that have to be accessed with a key.
Type of Keys is string (max:50 character) and Data is array of bytes (max:500 Byte).

I used this way :
define this types :

```
type  
  TMyBuf          = array[0..(500-1)] of Byte;
  TMyKey          = string[50];
  TMyBufs         = TDictionary<TMyKey,TMyBuf>;
var
  MyBufs     :TMyBufs;
```

and used :

```
var vMyBuf     :TMyBuf;
    vMyData    :TBytes ABSOLUTE vMyBuf;
    vMyDataLen :Word;
begin
    List := srvData.Contexts.LockList;
    SetLength(vMyBuf, 500);
    try
      if(List.Count > 0) then begin
        for i := 0 to List.Count-1 do begin
          with TMyContext(List[I]) do begin
            if SetedIdent then begin
              try
                vMyBuf:= MyBufs.Items[SeledData];
                //extract length of data which stored in two byte
                vMyDataLen:= ( ( (vMyBuf[1] shl 8)and $FF00) or (vMyBuf[0] and $FF) );
                Connection.IOHandler.Write(vMYData, vMYDataLen);
              finally
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      srvData.Contexts.UnlockList;
      SetLength(vMyBuf, 0);
    end;
end;
```

There is a similar code to write data.
**1**.Is it direct access to the Values? No need to copy the Value dictionary(`vMyBuf:= MyBufs.Items[SeledData];`).

**2**.Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off to make use of the implicit by-reference semantics of Classes
and use TObjectDictionary.

```
type  
  TMyBuf          = class
      public
       Data:array[0..(500-1)] of Byte;
  end;
  TMyKey          = string[50];
  TMyBufs         = TObjectDictionary<TMyKey,TMyBuf>;
var
  MyBufs     :TMyBufs;
```

This would allow you to write a single byte into the dictionary easily. You would of course have to allocate each TMyBuf by invoking it's constructor.  Similarly cleaning up would be easier if you used a TObjectDictionary which can own (meaning therefore know how to free) all object references placed into it.

The other thing you might not know is that on a Unicode delphi, `string[50]` is an ancient TurboPascal/DOS-era `shortstring` type and not a unicode string.

I suggest that unless you REALLY need to, you not worry about using string[50] and simply use string.  If you wish to validate at runtime that the string is 50 characters or less and throw an exception, then do it that way.

Comment: Thanks, I do not need Unicode.
And still did not answer the second question.